# Показ изображения только при первом заходе на страницу

Tags: javascript, cookie, img, время

По сути, в заголовке отразил основную тематику обращения) Как пример, пользователь заходит первый раз на страницу и видит изображение, при повторном заходе на страницу он этого изображения видеть не должен!

Применил такой способ:

CSS:

```
 #first { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
 <img id="first" src="any/path.jpg" alt="Show once" />
```

JS:

```
 function getCookie(c_name)
 {
      if (document.cookie.length>0)
      {
           c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
           if (c_start != -1)
           {
                return true;
           }
      }
      return false;
 }

 var showIt = getCookie('show');
 if (!showIt) {
      document.getElementById('first').style.display='bl ock';
      document.cookie='show=true; path=/; expires=Mon, 01-Jan-2020 00:00:00 GMT';
 }
```

При первых заходах все работало на УРА! Но теперь при заходе с других пк изображение вовсе не появляется(

Comment: у вас опечатка в style.display='bl ock'; уберите пробел и сделайте 'block'

Answer (score 1):

Я специально, когда ваш код чистил строку

```
document.getElementById('first').style.display='bl ock';
```

оставил - как есть.

'bl ock' - нет такого метода отображения.